# What determines sizeof(int)

Tags: microcontroller, c, atmega, embedded

Regarding the standard data types, What is the size of an integer in ATmega controllers? And what determines the size, is it just the compiler? Or is it in the hardware design of the controller itself and therefore all ATmega compilers have to abide to that size? And if it is in the hardware, how come that in a PC you can have two different compilers giving of different results for sizeof( int) even thou they run on the same processor?

Comment: The compiler does.

Comment: The compiler has a fixed width for int. A standards-compliant compiler must use a minimum width for int (16 bits) but there is no maximum, so two compliant compilers could use different widths even though they are emitting code for the same platform.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'd rather say: "The compiler knows the size when compiling." - It may vary by target platform, and there are things like [`-mint8`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#line-28). So, the actual size depends, but the compiler definitely knows/decides on it at compile time.

Comment: If your question has been answered, can you please mark one of the answers as accepted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`int` is a C type. The ATMega's have no concept of it, they work only with 8bit bytes (because they have 8bit AVR CPUs).

The compiler converts any operations on `int` types to the equivalent operations required to perform that operation at size level required by the CPU architecture - for an AVR, it is converted to do operations at the byte level, for a 16bit CPU, it would be done at the 16bit level, etc.

In `avr-gcc` an `int` type is simply defined in the compiler as a [2 byte integer](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc). The fact that it changes based on platform means you are better off using the `<stdint.h>` types such as `uint16_t` if you want to be sure of the size in code which needs to be portable. There are types defined for all standard integer sizes (8,16,32,64) in both signed and unsigned.

There are other definitions for so called `_fast` types which are guaranteed to be at least the required size, but will produce the fastest code based on the platform, for example 32bit processors tend to perform operations on 32bit numbers more efficiently than say 8bit numbers, so uint_fast8_t on a 32bit platform would be a 32bit integer (it's at least 8 bits, but is faster to handle).

The `sizeof()` instruction is performed at compile time, and converted to a constant, it is not executed by the processor. `avr-gcc` knows how big it has defined an `int` as, so it knows what constant to replace the `sizeof()` call with.

Comment: I don't think int is typedef'ed as anything. I think the compiler 'decides', the decision is built into the compiler. Can you provide a link,  or evidence?

Comment: You could add `uint_fast8_t` and `uint_least8_t` to your list - using these along with `uint8_t` (when fixed width is required) lets you write much more portable code.

Comment: avr-gcc doesn't seem to recognize int8_t type. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BlackyDucky you need to ```#include <stdint.h>``` - I had mentioned that, but the text parser had removed it because of the <> around it, sorry about that, fixed now.

Comment: Knowing that the AVRs are natively 8-bit, it may raise the question of why not just make "int" 8-bit for AVR-GCC - the reason for this is that the C language requires "int" to be minimum 16 bit / 2 chars so making it 8 bit would make it non-compliant with the C standard (and some assumptions, such as int being a larger type than char, will also not be true).  Math with 8-bit types (char / uint8_t) will still usually be faster because single 16 bit math expressions need to be compiled into multiple 8-bit instructions.

Answer (score 6):

The sizes of `int`, `short int`, `long int`, etc are decided by the people who write the compiler. The rules of C are that `short int` <= `int` <= `long int`, but that leaves plenty of room for the compiler writers.

Compiler writers analyse the processors's capabilities and try to make sensible choices for that CPU. They often give command-line flags to force an `int` to be a specific size to make it easier to port code across processors.

Different sequences of code are generated by the compiler to handle different sizes of int; the CPU is driven by the code, and so implements the size defined by the compilers output.

The Atmega's use AVR's CPU architecture. It mostly processes 8bits of data at a time. So the compiler has to generate code to implement multi-byte arithmetic.

The underlying address spaces of most ATmege's is 16 bits, so it is very convenient to have arithmetic which can access all of that. Hence, by default, an `int` is 16 bits. In the 'olden days' of x86 with segmented memory, where addresses could be 16 bits or 32 bits, and the compiler directed to generate cde for a particular 'model', the compiler usually generated code for a size of `int` that could hold the size of pointer for that 'memory model'.

If you use a compiler for the same processor, able to generate code for two (or more) different sizes of int (`int`, not `short int`, `long int`, just `int`), then that is exactly what it'll do in response to the appropriate flags (or pragma's).

The compiler 'knows' what size of `int` is it generating code for, so a `sizeof(int)` will be replaced by the correct value, at compile time, by the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

The sizes of the standard C data types are determined by the compiler implementation. According to the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), an int must be able to contains values in the range of -32767 to 32767 (16 bits), but may be larger. The size of an int is typically the most natural value for the CPU -- the word size, or the size of a CPU register.

The only way to know for sure is to consult your compiler manual or write test code. It's a good idea to have a copy of the manual for an embedded compiler since the specifics of alignment and data storage are more likely to matter in embedded programming. Compiler extensions (such as for interrupt support) are also more important.

If you have a C99-compliant compiler, it's easier to use the uintX_t types defined in  to get the size you want.

For reference, here are the minimum sizes for other data types taken from section 5.2.4.2.1 of the C99 standard. Note that two's complement arithmetic is not required, although I don't know of any one's complement or sign-magnitude machines off the top of my head.

**char (byte size):** sizeof(char) always equals 1. Signed chars must hold values in the range -127 to 127. Unsigned chars must hold values in the range 0 to 255. The standard also specifies the minimum number of bits in a char/byte, which is 8.

**short:** -32767 to 32767 for signed, 0 to 65535 for unsigned. Equivalent to 16 bits.

**int:** Same as short.

**long:** -2147483647 to 2147483647 for signed, 0 to 4294967295 for unsigned. Equivalent to 32 bits.

**long long:** -9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807 for signed, 0 to 18446744073709551615 for unsigned. Equivalent to 64 bits.

**pointer:** Implementation defined. The standard allows different "representation and alignment requirements" for pointers to different data types, but I've never seen that in practice.